How to export to pdf file using jasperreport version less than 6.21.2?
Right now, my frontend use a plugin for digital signature, it works well with backend. I want to use jasperreport in backend to create a pdf file but when I use it, the plugin below raise an error, it said it cannot upload file to server although it still upload successfully. I try many times and I realize that jasperreport cause it, I try to downgrade from v7.0.0 to v6.21.2 and then to v6.17.0. With jasperreport v6.17.0, the plugin works well but jasperreport doesnt, it raise and error:

NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfContentByte

My pom file have these line:
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.17.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.17.0</version>
</dependency>

What I can do now?
